# How to convert date and time fields to right datetime format for NOW() comparsion in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I use MySQL 5.7 and I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
  publish_date,
  publish_time,
  CONCAT(publish_date, ' ', publish_time) <= NOW() AS is_visible
FROM posts
ORDER BY
  publish_date DESC,
  publish_time DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

The current timestamp is: `2021-08-06 15:17:00`

I get this result:

```
| publish_date | publish_time | is_visible |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| 2021-08-06   | 17:00:00     |          0 |
| 2021-08-06   | 14:00:00     |          0 |
| 2021-07-31   | 08:00:00     |          1 |
```

But I wait this result, because of the 14:00:00 time is elapsed:

```
| publish_date | publish_time | is_visible |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| 2021-08-06   | 17:00:00     |          0 |
| 2021-08-06   | 14:00:00     |          1 |
| 2021-07-31   | 08:00:00     |          1 |
```

I tried to convert date and time fields to real datetime or timestamp object, but not help.

How can I get this result in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: What are the data types of publish_date and publish_time? Are you sure about the current timestamp in your server?

Comment: publish_date is date and publish_time is time type ... I'm sure, I can read it via `date` unix command in shell.

Comment: Is storing date ad time separately the best idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built-in [TIMESTAMP(date,time)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

```
SELECT
  publish_date,
  publish_time,
  TIMESTAMP(publish_date,publish_time) <= NOW() AS is_visible
FROM posts
ORDER BY
  publish_date DESC,
  publish_time DESC
LIMIT 3;
```